# Soft keyboard hides edit text inside scroll view(Xamarin Android)

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-softkeyboard

I new developer for 'Xamarin Android' ,i faced one issue now i will explain.

Inside scroll view have multiple edit text ,when i click or focus last edit text showing soft key board,but what problem means soft keyboard hides last edit text,but cursor was focused and also typed.

Now i need when i click or focus edit text means edit text show only above the soft key board.

I already fixed same issue in android studio using window Soft Input Mode = 'adjust pan|adjust resize' like,but in 'Xamarin android'  i added both soft input parameter,but i can't get output please any one help me.

```
Example Class

    LlLayout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.ABL_Runtime);

                ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
                //sv.LayoutParameters = linearLayoutParams;

                ABlayout = new AbsoluteLayout(this);
                //ABlayout.LayoutParameters = linearLayoutParams;

                AppConstant.pLastControlTop = AppConstant.pLastControlTop + AppConstant.pSpaceBetweenControl;
                EditText txtTitle = new EditText(this);
                txtTitle.Text = "Job ID 1";
                txtTitle.Tag = "Job ID sent from HO";
                txtTitle.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(redHex));
                txtTitle.SetX(AppConstant.pControlLeft);
                txtTitle.SetY(AppConstant.pLastControlTop);
                txtTitle.SetWidth((int)AppConstant.pFieldLen);

                LObj.Add(txtTitle);

                //txtTitle.SetTextColor(Color.ParseColor(""+ColorValue));
                txtTitle.SetHeight((int)AppConstant.pControlHeight);
                //int ColorValue = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("blue").GetHashCode();
                txtTitle.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(redHex));
                ABlayout.AddView(txtTitle);

                AppConstant.pLastControlTop = AppConstant.pLastControlTop + AppConstant.pControlHeight;
                txtTitle = new EditText(this);
                txtTitle.Text = "Job ID 2";
                txtTitle.Tag = "Job ID sent from HO";
                txtTitle.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(redHex));
                txtTitle.SetX(AppConstant.pControlLeft);
                txtTitle.SetY(AppConstant.pLastControlTop);
                txtTitle.SetWidth((int)AppConstant.pFieldLen);

                LObj.Add(txtTitle);

                //txtTitle.SetTextColor(Color.ParseColor(""+ColorValue));
                txtTitle.SetHeight((int)AppConstant.pControlHeight);
                //int ColorValue = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("blue").GetHashCode();
                txtTitle.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(redHex));
                ABlayout.AddView(txtTitle);

                AppConstant.pLastControlTop = AppConstant.pLastControlTop + AppConstant.pControlHeight;
                txtTitle = new EditText(this);
                txtTitle.Text = "Job ID 3";
                txtTitle.Tag = "Job ID sent from HO";
                txtTitle.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(redHex));
                txtTitle.SetX(AppConstant.pControlLeft);
                txtTitle.SetY(AppConstant.pLastControlTop);
                txtTitle.SetWidth((int)AppConstant.pFieldLen);

                LObj.Add(txtTitle);

                //txtTitle.SetTextColor(Color.ParseColor(""+ColorValue));
                txtTitle.SetHeight((int)AppConstant.pControlHeight);
                //int ColorValue = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("blue").GetHashCode();
                txtTitle.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(redHex));
                ABlayout.AddView(txtTitle);

                AppConstant.pLastControlTop = AppConstant.pLastControlTop + AppConstant.pControlHeight;
                txtTitle = new EditText(this);
                txtTitle.Text = "Job ID 4";
                txtTitle.Tag = "Job ID sent from HO";
                txtTitle.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(redHex));
                txtTitle.SetX(AppConstant.pControlLeft);
                txtTitle.SetY(AppConstant.pLastControlTop);
                txtTitle.SetWidth((int)AppConstant.pFieldLen);

                LObj.Add(txtTitle);

                //txtTitle.SetTextColor(Color.ParseColor(""+ColorValue));
                txtTitle.SetHeight((int)AppConstant.pControlHeight);
                //int ColorValue = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("blue").GetHashCode();
                txtTitle.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(redHex));
                ABlayout.AddView(txtTitle);

                AppConstant.pLastControlTop = AppConstant.pLastControlTop + AppConstant.pControlHeight;
                txtTitle = new EditText(this);
                txtTitle.Text = "Job ID 5";
                txtTitle.Tag = "Job ID sent from HO";
                txtTitle.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(redHex));
                txtTitle.SetX(AppConstant.pControlLeft);
                txtTitle.SetY(AppConstant.pLastControlTop);
                txtTitle.SetWidth((int)AppConstant.pFieldLen);

                LObj.Add(txtTitle);

                //txtTitle.SetTextColor(Color.ParseColor(""+ColorValue));
                txtTitle.SetHeight((int)AppConstant.pControlHeight);
                //int ColorValue = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("blue").GetHashCode();
                txtTitle.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(redHex));
                ABlayout.AddView(txtTitle);

                AppConstant.pLastControlTop = AppConstant.pLastControlTop + AppConstant.pSpaceBetweenControl;
                txtTitle = new EditText(this);
                txtTitle.Text = "Job ID 6";
                txtTitle.Tag = "Job ID sent from HO";
                txtTitle.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(redHex));
                txtTitle.SetX(AppConstant.pControlLeft);
                txtTitle.SetY(AppConstant.pLastControlTop);
                txtTitle.SetWidth((int)AppConstant.pFieldLen);

                LObj.Add(txtTitle);

                //txtTitle.SetTextColor(Color.ParseColor(""+ColorValue));
                txtTitle.SetHeight((int)AppConstant.pControlHeight);
                //int ColorValue = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("blue").GetHashCode();
                txtTitle.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(redHex));
                ABlayout.AddView(txtTitle);

                AppConstant.pLastControlTop = AppConstant.pLastControlTop + AppConstant.pControlHeight;
                txtTitle = new EditText(this);
                txtTitle.Text = "Job ID 7";
                txtTitle.Tag = "Job ID sent from HO";
                txtTitle.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(redHex));
                txtTitle.SetX(AppConstant.pControlLeft);
                txtTitle.SetY(AppConstant.pLastControlTop);
                txtTitle.SetWidth((int)AppConstant.pFieldLen);

                LObj.Add(txtTitle);

                //txtTitle.SetTextColor(Color.ParseColor(""+ColorValue));
                txtTitle.SetHeight((int)AppConstant.pControlHeight);
                //int ColorValue = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("blue").GetHashCode();
                txtTitle.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(redHex));
                ABlayout.AddView(txtTitle);

                AppConstant.pLastControlTop = AppConstant.pLastControlTop + AppConstant.pControlHeight;
                txtTitle = new EditText(this);
                txtTitle.Text = "Job ID 8";
                txtTitle.Tag = "Job ID sent from HO";
                txtTitle.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(redHex));
                txtTitle.SetX(AppConstant.pControlLeft);
                txtTitle.SetY(AppConstant.pLastControlTop);
                txtTitle.SetWidth((int)AppConstant.pFieldLen);

                LObj.Add(txtTitle);

                //txtTitle.SetTextColor(Color.ParseColor(""+ColorValue));
                txtTitle.SetHeight((int)AppConstant.pControlHeight);
                //int ColorValue = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("blue").GetHashCode();
                txtTitle.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(redHex));
                ABlayout.AddView(txtTitle);

                AppConstant.pLastControlTop = AppConstant.pLastControlTop + AppConstant.pControlHeight;
                txtTitle = new EditText(this);
                txtTitle.Text = "Job ID 10";
                txtTitle.Tag = "Job ID sent from HO";
                txtTitle.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(redHex));
                txtTitle.SetX(AppConstant.pControlLeft);
                txtTitle.SetY(AppConstant.pLastControlTop);
                txtTitle.SetWidth((int)AppConstant.pFieldLen);

                LObj.Add(txtTitle);

                //txtTitle.SetTextColor(Color.ParseColor(""+ColorValue));
                txtTitle.SetHeight((int)AppConstant.pControlHeight);
                //int ColorValue = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("blue").GetHashCode();
                txtTitle.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(redHex));
                ABlayout.AddView(txtTitle);

                AppConstant.pLastControlTop = AppConstant.pLastControlTop + AppConstant.pControlHeight;
                txtTitle = new EditText(this);
                txtTitle.Text = "Job ID 11";
                txtTitle.Tag = "Job ID sent from HO";
                txtTitle.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(redHex));
                txtTitle.SetX(AppConstant.pControlLeft);
                txtTitle.SetY(AppConstant.pLastControlTop);
                txtTitle.SetWidth((int)AppConstant.pFieldLen);

                LObj.Add(txtTitle);

                //txtTitle.SetTextColor(Color.ParseColor(""+ColorValue));
                txtTitle.SetHeight((int)AppConstant.pControlHeight);
                //int ColorValue = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("blue").GetHashCode();
                txtTitle.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(redHex));
                ABlayout.AddView(txtTitle);

                AppConstant.pLastControlTop = AppConstant.pLastControlTop + AppConstant.pControlHeight;
                txtTitle = new EditText(this);
                txtTitle.Text = "Job ID 12";
                txtTitle.Tag = "Job ID sent from HO";
                txtTitle.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(redHex));
                txtTitle.SetX(AppConstant.pControlLeft);
                txtTitle.SetY(AppConstant.pLastControlTop);
                txtTitle.SetWidth((int)AppConstant.pFieldLen);

                LObj.Add(txtTitle);

                //txtTitle.SetTextColor(Color.ParseColor(""+ColorValue));
                txtTitle.SetHeight((int)AppConstant.pControlHeight);
                //int ColorValue = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("blue").GetHashCode();
                txtTitle.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(redHex));
                ABlayout.AddView(txtTitle);

                AppConstant.pLastControlTop = AppConstant.pLastControlTop + AppConstant.pControlHeight;
                txtTitle = new EditText(this);
                txtTitle.Text = "Job ID 13";
                txtTitle.Tag = "Job ID sent from HO";
                txtTitle.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(redHex));
                txtTitle.SetX(AppConstant.pControlLeft);
                txtTitle.SetY(AppConstant.pLastControlTop);
                txtTitle.SetWidth((int)AppConstant.pFieldLen);

                LObj.Add(txtTitle);

                //txtTitle.SetTextColor(Color.ParseColor(""+ColorValue));
                txtTitle.SetHeight((int)AppConstant.pControlHeight);
                //int ColorValue = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("blue").GetHashCode();
                txtTitle.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(redHex));
                ABlayout.AddView(txtTitle);

                AppConstant.pLastControlTop = AppConstant.pLastControlTop + AppConstant.pControlHeight;
                txtTitle = new EditText(this);
                txtTitle.Text = "Job ID 14";
                txtTitle.Tag = "Job ID sent from HO";
                txtTitle.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(redHex));
                txtTitle.SetX(AppConstant.pControlLeft);
                txtTitle.SetY(AppConstant.pLastControlTop);
                txtTitle.SetWidth((int)AppConstant.pFieldLen);

                LObj.Add(txtTitle);

                //txtTitle.SetTextColor(Color.ParseColor(""+ColorValue));
                txtTitle.SetHeight((int)AppConstant.pControlHeight);
                //int ColorValue = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("blue").GetHashCode();
                txtTitle.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(redHex));
                ABlayout.AddView(txtTitle);

                AppConstant.pLastControlTop = AppConstant.pLastControlTop + AppConstant.pControlHeight;
                txtTitle = new EditText(this);
                txtTitle.Text = "Job ID 15";
                txtTitle.Tag = "Job ID sent from HO";
                txtTitle.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(redHex));
                txtTitle.SetX(AppConstant.pControlLeft);
                txtTitle.SetY(AppConstant.pLastControlTop);
                txtTitle.SetWidth((int)AppConstant.pFieldLen);

                LObj.Add(txtTitle);

                //txtTitle.SetTextColor(Color.ParseColor(""+ColorValue));
                txtTitle.SetHeight((int)AppConstant.pControlHeight);
                //int ColorValue = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("blue").GetHashCode();
                txtTitle.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(redHex));
                ABlayout.AddView(txtTitle);

                AppConstant.pLastControlTop = AppConstant.pLastControlTop + AppConstant.pControlHeight;
                txtTitle = new EditText(this);
                txtTitle.Text = "Job ID 16";
                txtTitle.Tag = "Job ID sent from HO";
                txtTitle.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(redHex));
                txtTitle.SetX(AppConstant.pControlLeft);
                txtTitle.SetY(AppConstant.pLastControlTop);
                txtTitle.SetWidth((int)AppConstant.pFieldLen);

                LObj.Add(txtTitle);

                //txtTitle.SetTextColor(Color.ParseColor(""+ColorValue));
                txtTitle.SetHeight((int)AppConstant.pControlHeight);
                //int ColorValue = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("blue").GetHashCode();
                txtTitle.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(redHex));
                ABlayout.AddView(txtTitle);

                AppConstant.pLastControlTop = AppConstant.pLastControlTop + AppConstant.pControlHeight;
                txtTitle = new EditText(this);
                txtTitle.Text = "Job ID 17";
                txtTitle.Tag = "Job ID sent from HO";
                txtTitle.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(redHex));
                txtTitle.SetX(AppConstant.pControlLeft);
                txtTitle.SetY(AppConstant.pLastControlTop);
                txtTitle.SetWidth((int)AppConstant.pFieldLen);

                LObj.Add(txtTitle);

                //txtTitle.SetTextColor(Color.ParseColor(""+ColorValue));
                txtTitle.SetHeight((int)AppConstant.pControlHeight);
                //int ColorValue = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("blue").GetHashCode();
                txtTitle.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(redHex));
                ABlayout.AddView(txtTitle);

                AppConstant.pLastControlTop = AppConstant.pLastControlTop + AppConstant.pControlHeight;
                txtTitle = new EditText(this);
                txtTitle.Text = "Job ID 18";
                txtTitle.Tag = "Job ID sent from HO";
                txtTitle.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(redHex));
                txtTitle.SetX(AppConstant.pControlLeft);
                txtTitle.SetY(AppConstant.pLastControlTop);
                txtTitle.SetWidth((int)AppConstant.pFieldLen);

                LObj.Add(txtTitle);

                //txtTitle.SetTextColor(Color.ParseColor(""+ColorValue));
                txtTitle.SetHeight((int)AppConstant.pControlHeight);
                //int ColorValue = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("blue").GetHashCode();
                txtTitle.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(redHex));
                ABlayout.AddView(txtTitle);

                AppConstant.pLastControlTop = AppConstant.pLastControlTop + AppConstant.pControlHeight;
                txtTitle = new EditText(this);
                txtTitle.Text = "Job ID 19";
                txtTitle.Tag = "Job ID sent from HO";
                txtTitle.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(redHex));
                txtTitle.SetX(AppConstant.pControlLeft);
                txtTitle.SetY(AppConstant.pLastControlTop);
                txtTitle.SetWidth((int)AppConstant.pFieldLen);

                LObj.Add(txtTitle);

                //txtTitle.SetTextColor(Color.ParseColor(""+ColorValue));
                txtTitle.SetHeight((int)AppConstant.pControlHeight);
                //int ColorValue = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("blue").GetHashCode();
                txtTitle.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(redHex));
                ABlayout.AddView(txtTitle);

                AppConstant.pLastControlTop = AppConstant.pLastControlTop + AppConstant.pControlHeight;
                txtTitle = new EditText(this);
                txtTitle.Text = "Job ID 20";
                txtTitle.Tag = "Job ID sent from HO";
                txtTitle.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(redHex));
                txtTitle.SetX(AppConstant.pControlLeft);
                txtTitle.SetY(AppConstant.pLastControlTop);
                txtTitle.SetWidth((int)AppConstant.pFieldLen);

                LObj.Add(txtTitle);

                //txtTitle.SetTextColor(Color.ParseColor(""+ColorValue));
                txtTitle.SetHeight((int)AppConstant.pControlHeight);
                //int ColorValue = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("blue").GetHashCode();
                txtTitle.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(redHex));
                ABlayout.AddView(txtTitle);

                AppConstant.pLastControlTop = AppConstant.pLastControlTop + AppConstant.pControlHeight;
                txtTitle = new EditText(this);
                txtTitle.Text = "Job ID 21";
                txtTitle.Tag = "Job ID sent from HO";
                txtTitle.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(redHex));
                txtTitle.SetX(AppConstant.pControlLeft);
                txtTitle.SetY(AppConstant.pLastControlTop);
                txtTitle.SetWidth((int)AppConstant.pFieldLen);

                LObj.Add(txtTitle);

                //txtTitle.SetTextColor(Color.ParseColor(""+ColorValue));
                txtTitle.SetHeight((int)AppConstant.pControlHeight);
                //int ColorValue = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("blue").GetHashCode();
                txtTitle.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(redHex));
                ABlayout.AddView(txtTitle);

                AppConstant.pLastControlTop = AppConstant.pLastControlTop + AppConstant.pControlHeight;
                txtTitle = new EditText(this);
                txtTitle.Text = "Job ID 22";
                txtTitle.Tag = "Job ID sent from HO";
                txtTitle.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(redHex));
                txtTitle.SetX(AppConstant.pControlLeft);
                txtTitle.SetY(AppConstant.pLastControlTop);
                txtTitle.SetWidth((int)AppConstant.pFieldLen);

                LObj.Add(txtTitle);

                //txtTitle.SetTextColor(Color.ParseColor(""+ColorValue));
                txtTitle.SetHeight((int)AppConstant.pControlHeight);
                //int ColorValue = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("blue").GetHashCode();
                txtTitle.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(redHex));
                ABlayout.AddView(txtTitle);

                AppConstant.pLastControlTop = AppConstant.pLastControlTop + AppConstant.pControlHeight;
                txtTitle = new EditText(this);
                txtTitle.Text = "Job ID 23";
                txtTitle.Tag = "Job ID sent from HO";
                txtTitle.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(redHex));
                txtTitle.SetX(AppConstant.pControlLeft);
                txtTitle.SetY(AppConstant.pLastControlTop);
                txtTitle.SetWidth((int)AppConstant.pFieldLen);

                LObj.Add(txtTitle);

                //txtTitle.SetTextColor(Color.ParseColor(""+ColorValue));
                txtTitle.SetHeight((int)AppConstant.pControlHeight);
                //int ColorValue = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("blue").GetHashCode();
                txtTitle.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(redHex));
                ABlayout.AddView(txtTitle);

                AppConstant.pLastControlTop = AppConstant.pLastControlTop + AppConstant.pControlHeight;
                txtTitle = new EditText(this);
                txtTitle.Text = "Job ID 24";
                txtTitle.Tag = "Job ID sent from HO";
                txtTitle.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(redHex));
                txtTitle.SetX(AppConstant.pControlLeft);
                txtTitle.SetY(AppConstant.pLastControlTop);
                txtTitle.SetWidth((int)AppConstant.pFieldLen);

                LObj.Add(txtTitle);

                //txtTitle.SetTextColor(Color.ParseColor(""+ColorValue));
                txtTitle.SetHeight((int)AppConstant.pControlHeight);
                //int ColorValue = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("blue").GetHashCode();
                txtTitle.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(redHex));
                ABlayout.AddView(txtTitle);

                AppConstant.pLastControlTop = AppConstant.pLastControlTop + AppConstant.pControlHeight;
                txtTitle = new EditText(this);
                txtTitle.Text = "Job ID 25";
                txtTitle.Tag = "Job ID sent from HO";
                txtTitle.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(redHex));
                txtTitle.SetX(AppConstant.pControlLeft);
                txtTitle.SetY(AppConstant.pLastControlTop);
                txtTitle.SetWidth((int)AppConstant.pFieldLen);

                LObj.Add(txtTitle);

                //txtTitle.SetTextColor(Color.ParseColor(""+ColorValue));
                txtTitle.SetHeight((int)AppConstant.pControlHeight);
                //int ColorValue = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("blue").GetHashCode();
                txtTitle.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(redHex));
                ABlayout.AddView(txtTitle);

                AppConstant.pLastControlTop = AppConstant.pLastControlTop + AppConstant.pControlHeight;
                txtTitle = new EditText(this);
                txtTitle.Text = "Job ID 26";
                txtTitle.Tag = "Job ID sent from HO";
                txtTitle.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(redHex));
                txtTitle.SetX(AppConstant.pControlLeft);
                txtTitle.SetY(AppConstant.pLastControlTop);
                txtTitle.SetWidth((int)AppConstant.pFieldLen);

                LObj.Add(txtTitle);

                //txtTitle.SetTextColor(Color.ParseColor(""+ColorValue));
                txtTitle.SetHeight((int)AppConstant.pControlHeight);
                //int ColorValue = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("blue").GetHashCode();
                txtTitle.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(redHex));
                ABlayout.AddView(txtTitle);

                AppConstant.pLastControlTop = AppConstant.pLastControlTop + AppConstant.pControlHeight;
                txtTitle = new EditText(this);
                txtTitle.Text = "Job ID 27";
                txtTitle.Tag = "Job ID sent from HO";
                txtTitle.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(redHex));
                txtTitle.SetX(AppConstant.pControlLeft);
                txtTitle.SetY(AppConstant.pLastControlTop);
                txtTitle.SetWidth((int)AppConstant.pFieldLen);

                LObj.Add(txtTitle);

                //txtTitle.SetTextColor(Color.ParseColor(""+ColorValue));
                txtTitle.SetHeight((int)AppConstant.pControlHeight);
                //int ColorValue = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("blue").GetHashCode();
                txtTitle.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(redHex));
                ABlayout.AddView(txtTitle);

                AppConstant.pLastControlTop = AppConstant.pLastControlTop + AppConstant.pControlHeight;
                txtTitle = new EditText(this);
                txtTitle.Text = "Job ID 28";
                txtTitle.Tag = "Job ID sent from HO";
                txtTitle.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(redHex));
                txtTitle.SetX(AppConstant.pControlLeft);
                txtTitle.SetY(AppConstant.pLastControlTop);
                txtTitle.SetWidth((int)AppConstant.pFieldLen);

                LObj.Add(txtTitle);

                //txtTitle.SetTextColor(Color.ParseColor(""+ColorValue));
                txtTitle.SetHeight((int)AppConstant.pControlHeight);
                //int ColorValue = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("blue").GetHashCode();
                txtTitle.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(redHex));
                ABlayout.AddView(txtTitle);

                AppConstant.pLastControlTop = AppConstant.pLastControlTop + AppConstant.pControlHeight;
                txtTitle = new EditText(this);
                txtTitle.Text = "Job ID 29";
                txtTitle.Tag = "Job ID sent from HO";
                txtTitle.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(redHex));
                txtTitle.SetX(AppConstant.pControlLeft);
                txtTitle.SetY(AppConstant.pLastControlTop);
                txtTitle.SetWidth((int)AppConstant.pFieldLen);

                LObj.Add(txtTitle);

                //txtTitle.SetTextColor(Color.ParseColor(""+ColorValue));
                txtTitle.SetHeight((int)AppConstant.pControlHeight);
                //int ColorValue = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("blue").GetHashCode();
                txtTitle.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(redHex));
                ABlayout.AddView(txtTitle);

                LlLayout.AddView(ABlayout);

Example XML File

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/ABL_Runtime">

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

> I edited my Question with example class and xml ,i created edit text run time and also get values runtime.Here i m using absolute layout for set edittext based on x ,y position.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use only one of them instead:

```
Window.SetSoftInputMode(SoftInput.AdjustPan);
```

The activity's main window is not resized to make room for the soft keyboard. Rather, the contents of the window are automatically panned so that the current focus is never obscured by the keyboard and users can always see what they are typing. This is generally less desirable than resizing, because the user may need to close the soft keyboard to get at and interact with obscured parts of the window.

```
Window.SetSoftInputMode(SoftInput.AdjustResize);
```

> The activity's main window is always resized to make room for the soft
>   keyboard on screen.

If you are working on a Xamarin.forms project, you can read [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/android/soft-keyboard-input-mode) for more information.

Comment: Good Morning ,Thanks for your response,I tested its also not working,Buz  inside scrollview i used AbsoluteLayout ,then i added edit text with based on X Y position.

Comment: @saravanan Can you please share me a Minimal, Reproducible Example so that I can test it on my side? Or add some relevant code about that page?

Comment: Pls check my above example class and xml file,i created multiple edit text added to absolute layout .

Comment: What is LObj and AppConstant here?

Comment: List<object> LObj = new List<object>();

Comment: Appconstant is just one constant class

Comment: Can you please share me the Appconstant?